# BDB, How to get primary keys in specified order?

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting, selection, berkeley-db

I have asked the same question for some days on oracle forums, but no answer came:(
link is:http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2162345&tstart=0

Hi, I build BBS using BDB as backend database, forum database, topic database and post database share one environment. This BBS web application is multi-thread program. If user selects one forum, its topics will be listed in order of last reply time;selecting one topic, posts are listed in order of reply time as well.

```
struct forum {
UInt16 forumID;
string forumName;
string _lastPoster; // who is the last one replied in this forum
};

struct topic {
UInt32 topicID;
UInt16 forumID; // topic comes from this forum
string title; // topic title
UInt64 dateOfLastReply; // when last reply to this topic happen
};

struct post {
UInt64 postID;
UInt32 topicID; // post comes from this topic
string title; // post title as of topic
UInt64 dateOfPost; // when this post is created
};
```

I create one primary database and two secondary databases for topic, primary key is topicID, secondary keys are forumID and dateOfLastReply respectively, and I want to show 1st 25 topics in latest reply time order on the 1st browser page, 2nd 25 topics on the 2nd browser page, and etc.

if using SQL, it will be: **SELECT** topicID **FROM** topic **WHERE** forumID=xx **ORDER BY** dateOfLastReply **DESC**

From performance perspective, I want get all topics id of one same forum, and need them come in reply time order, then retrieve topic one by one based on returned topicID, how can I do this? guess I have to use joins.
Plus, do you have any suggestion about retrieval performance given the fact that topics retrieval will happen each time browser want to request the next page, that is, 2nd 25 topics of this forum?
Is DB_DBT_MULTIPLE helpful to me?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a secondary database with a composite key, consisting of (forum_id, dateoflastreply). Then, all the results you want will be in a contiguous range of rows, and you can query on them by doing a range scan (eg, 20 rows starting with (1, 2010-01-01)).

Comment: Hi Nick, I also think composite key maybe helpful to me, however, I don't know how to create composite key? is it DB_DBT_MULTIPLE? should I customize compare function? etc.sample code maybe better.

Comment: I haven't worked with BDB in a while, so I can't offer sample code. In general, all BDB values are bytes, so you need to create the composite value yourself by encoding the fields together. This should be simple if, for instance, both fields are fixed-length - just concatenate them together. As long as the encoded value sorts bytewise in the expected fashion, you won't need a custom comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using BDB's new [SQL access layers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/sql-160887.html)?   If so, just use SQL.

If not, BDB is (mostly) just a key-value datastore.   It has several access methods (hash, B+tree, etc), but at its core thats all it is.  If you want to sort/search by non-primary keys, you'll have to create indexes on those values, and do the searching/joining in your own code.

Comment: Hi, I'm using non-sql version BDB. Yes, I know BDB is a key-value database, and I have created secondary indexes as well, however, I can't find any way to meet my requirements as described in my question

Comment: If your secondary index is on dateoflastreply, then you'd just iterate on that range.  You'd still have to manually compare each one with your WHERE forumID condition though.   Thats what a database engine would do for you internally anyways.

Comment: Hi Corey, do you mean BDB won't sort record while inserting or updating? Originally, I think BDB will use compare function set by set_bt_compare to sort records whil inserting or updating.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the topic_secondary database (which contains the secondary keys) is defined via DB_ASSOCIATE, then you would open a cursor on the topic_secondary database and using DBC->get() with DB_SET_RANGE you would position the cursor on the desired forumID and move the cursor forward from there.

By using a cursor over the secondary database, you get the data returned from the primary database in the desired order. And by specifying the forumID in the initial DBC->get() with DB_SET_RANGE, you can position the cursor at the proper place to begin your scan.

Please see the documentation on [Cursors](http://bit.ly/hj08C2) and [Secondary indexes](http://bit.ly/hHyxAE).

Please let me know if this answers your question.

Regards,

Dave

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and I will give it try. As I know, sorting will happen while inserting, that is, if I want get desired order, I have to keep those records sorted after inserting(put) instead of get; surely, app can do sorting after all desired records returned, but this maybe a penalty on performance

Comment: Depending on your index, keys are inserted in sorted order. I'm assuming that your tables are BTrees, in which case the data will be sorted based on the key.

Comment: Hi, I make sencondary database with composite key of forumID and dateOfLastReply, set compare function as well, which meets my requirement, thanks for your helpful answer

Comment: Tiplip, would you like to post your code here, on Github, Google Code, or elsewhere as an example? It would probably help the next person who's also interested in solving a similar problem with Berkeley DB.